# cvxpy.min or cvxpy.max in constraints

Tags: python, optimization, cvxpy

The following is my code:

```
import cvxpy as cp

alpha = 0.3
lamda_1 = 0.5
lamda_2 = 1.2

mu1 = cp.Variable(pos=True)
mu2 = cp.Variable(pos=True)
p_ev_max = 50
eps = 0.05
S1 = cp.Variable(pos=True)
S2 = cp.Variable(pos=True)
S = cp.Parameter(pos=True)
S.value = 200
# time resolution is 15 mins
obj = cp.Minimize(1/(mu1 - lamda_1)+1/(mu2 - lamda_2))
constraints = [
    mu1 == cp.min(p_ev_max, (1+eps)*S1),
    mu2 == cp.min(p_ev_max, (1+eps)*S2),
    S == S1 + S2,
]
prob = cp.Problem(objective= obj, constraints = constraints)
prob.solve(gp=True, requires_grad=True)
```

I get this error for using `cp.min` function:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 32, in <module>
  File "~/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/cvxpy/expressions/expression.py", line 661, in __lt__
    raise NotImplementedError("Strict inequalities are not allowed.")
NotImplementedError: Strict inequalities are not allowed.
```

I wonder how I am supposed to use the `cvxpy min max function`. I searched for the error but they were not relevant to using `cp.min` in the constraints.

Comment: I guess the `==` in `mu1 == cp.min...` is a problem as this usually means that you express both directions and with convexity/concavity, this might be a problem. In practice, you might try to get away with bounding your intermediate variables `mu_i` from below only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use vstack() in cvxpy to solve this problem:

```
mu1 == cp.min(cp.vstack([p_ev_max, (1+eps)*S1])),
mu2 == cp.min(cp.vstack([p_ev_max, (1+eps)*S2])),
```

I think vstack() combines multiple separate variables into one that is meet the requirement of cp.min